phpMyAdmin error #1044 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'
Problem
I am trying to modify the information_schema db table INNODB_SYS_TABLES to remove one row, but I keep getting the following error:
#1044 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema' 
However, I am already logged in to phpMyAdmin as:
root@localhost
with ALL PRIVILEGES set:
SELECT * FROM `USER_PRIVILEGES`: 



GRANTEE
TABLE_CATALOG
PRIVILEGE_TYPE
IS_GRANTABLE




'root'@'localhost'
def
SELECT
YES


'root'@'localhost'
def
INSERT
YES


'root'@'localhost'
def
UPDATE
YES


'root'@'localhost'
def
DELETE
YES



The full privileges table:



User name
Host name
Type
Privileges
Grant




mamp
localhost
global
ALL PRIVILEGES
Yes


root
127.0.0.1
global
ALL PRIVILEGES
Yes


root
::1
global
ALL PRIVILEGES
Yes


root
localhost
global
ALL PRIVILEGES
Yes



You get the idea...
Furthermore:
All the tables in this db are lacking a unique column, which strikes me as odd, since this is a 'system' database.
This results in the following phpMyAdmin warning:-
Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.
I tried to create a unique key on the table INNODB_SYS_TABLES but I get the same #1044 Access Denied error.
Ask
What do I need to do differently here to be able to delete a row in the information_schema db table INNODB_SYS_TABLES?
My environment
phpMyAdmin: v5.2.1 
MySQL: v5.7 
Server: MAMP PRO v7 
OS: Macos v11.7 

What is it you're trying to accomplish? I believe whatever it is that you're going about it the wrong way as that database isn't meant to be manipulated directly.
The deleted answer by technofreaks correctly says that INFORMATION_SCHEMA is read-only, so trying to write to it directly is not possible.
